# jQuery Append code snippet with its own JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, append

I am trying to do a jQuery append but I am faced with an issue.

This works fine:

```
onclick="$('#TAGS1').append('<div class=\'B9_N\'><?php echo $TAG_INFO['TAG']; ?></div>');"
```

But now, I cannot go further. I want something like this:

```
onclick="$('#TAGS1').append('<div class=\'B9_N\' **onmouseover=\"this.className=\'B8_A\';\"**><?php echo $TAG_INFO['TAG']; ?></div>');"
```

I want to append a TAG with its own JavaScript inside of it. This does not work at all. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid inline script and use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#TAGS1').click(function(){
     $(this).append('<div class="B9_N" />');
  });
  $('#TAGS1').hover(function(){
     $(this).addClass('B8_A');// perhaps you wanted to remove B9_N class, if so use $(this).removeClass('B9_N').addClass(B8_A');
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to change the class with hover over the div itself, not the tags section. The tags are added to the tags section in form of divs which have their own characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help! I did something like this:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $("#TAGS1").on("mouseover mouseout","div",function(){ $(this).toggleClass("B9_A"); }); });</script>
```